# Is there a way to pass Docker environments through to Angular Applications?

Tags: angular, docker, environment-variables, containers, external

I've got an Angular 7 application running in a docker container.

Now I need to change some environments and pass it through to the angular application. Is that possible? If so, how can I achieve this?

As an example:

The docker ENV variable has a string with content 'this is a tex'. Now I need to get this string into my application.

Comment: https://www.bennettnotes.com/post/angular-read-system-environment-variables/

Comment: Are you referring to **compile time** or **run-time**?